# lastInsertId() not working on a PDO object, in an insert operation

Tags: php, sql, pdo, last-insert-id

I initialize the class with these options:

```
$options = array(
      PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true, 
      PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
);
```

Then i behave like this

```
$this->sql = trim($sql);
$this->bind = $this->cleanup($bind);
$this->error = "";

try {
   $pdostmt = $this->prepare($this->sql);
   if($pdostmt->execute($this->bind) !== false) {
       if(preg_match("/^(" . implode("|", array("select", "describe", "pragma")) . ") /i", $this->sql))
           return $pdostmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
       elseif(preg_match("/^(" . implode("|", array("delete", "update")) . ") /i", $this->sql))
           return $pdostmt->rowCount();
       elseif(preg_match("/^(" . implode("|", array("insert")) . ") /i", $this->sql))
           return $pdostmt->lastInsertId();
}
```

that's because after an INSERT i need to return the last inserted id.
but i've been told lastInsertId() is not a function.
so it doesn't work.

any idea? maybe wrong options? 
thank you

Comment: this is OOP. Why stuff every bit of info into one single function? Why not to call for rowCount only when you need a rowCount, with a separate call?

Comment: you are right, i got the code from an online library, i modified it only in the **insert** if, just because of a need. when i will have more time to update it, and make it slimmer, i'll do that ;) anyway thank you for your notice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in the `PDO` object, not in a `PDOStatement`.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Comment: yes i noticed.... so stupid... sorry, long working period makes you blind..... thank you